# ! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }. <inserted text> \par } when trying to include graphics in title

Tags: graphics, titles

I want the `author` on the right side so I use `titling`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[width=150mm, top=12.5mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}}
\preauthor{\begin{flushright}}
\postauthor{\par\end{flushright}}

\title{
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{logo.png}\\
Dipartimento di Ingegneria dell'Informazione e Scienze Matematiche\\
\hfill \break
Masters of Science in Computer and Automation Engineering\\
\hfill \break
Thesis
}
\author{NSV}


\begin{document}

    \maketitle
    \include{chapters/chap1}
    \include{chapters/chap2}
    \include{chapters/chap3}
    \include{chapters/chap4}
    \include{chapters/chap5}

\end{document}
```

But I get the error `! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }. <inserted text> \par }` and `! Paragraph ended before \reserved@a was complete.<to be read again>\par }`

If I remove the below code, everything works but I have the `author` in the center.

```
\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}}
\preauthor{\begin{flushright}}
\postauthor{\par\end{flushright}}
```

Comment: please consider of changing the title to "`\includegraphics` inside `\title`" or something similar, that is more accurate and so more helpfull for future users [I mean that the `\reserved@a` part is too general and possibly "hides" your question from google search]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `\protect` the `\includegraphics` command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[width=150mm, top=12.5mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}}
\preauthor{\begin{flushright}}
\postauthor{\par\end{flushright}}

\title{%
\protect\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}\\
Dipartimento di Ingegneria dell'Informazione e Scienze Matematiche\\[\bigskipamount]
Masters of Science in Computer and Automation Engineering\\[\bigskipamount]
Thesis
}
\author{NSV}


\begin{document}

    \maketitle

\end{document}
```

Note also that instead of `\hfill\break` you should use the optional spacing command to `\\`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused from the `\includegraphics` inside the `\title` command

You can include it in `\@title` instead without problems by redefining `\@title`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[width=150mm, top=12.5mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE}
\posttitle{\end{center}}
\preauthor{\begin{flushright}}
\postauthor{\end{flushright}}

\title{
test\hfill test2 \hfill test3
}
\makeatletter
\let\oldtitle\@title
\def\@title{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}\\\oldtitle}
\makeatother
\author{NSV}


\begin{document}
    \maketitle


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]